# Translating "From Man to Woman" into Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I want to title a poem "From Man to Woman" in the sense, addressed to woman, by man. While starting the poem, I had the phrase *ad hominem/ad feminam* in mind. My knowledge of Latin ends there.

Google translate fetches something on the lines of
*ad femina ab homini*

Is this correct? If not, could you provide a short phrase, because it needs to be a title.

Answer (score 4):

For an idiomatic translation, I would suggest ***Vir Mulierī Salūtem Dīcit***.

This literally means "(a/the) man sends health to (a/the) woman", or more loosely, "the man greets the woman". This particular phrase is a standard formula in letter-writing: *X Y salutem dicit* was so common as the opening to a letter that it was usually abbreviated *X Y SD* in Classical times. For example, a letter from Marcus to Sextus would be addressed *Marcus Sextō salūtem dīcit* or *Marcus Sextō SD*, or even *M S SD* when using particularly common names.

---

The horizontal lines above the vowels represent a difference in sound that disappeared in later Latin, so you can include them or leave them off, at your preference.

---

The word *vir* means "man" as in "male human", as opposed to woman. If instead you want "man" to mean "any human", as in "mankind", use *homō* instead.

*Mulierī* is a nice simple word for "to a woman", but you could also use *fēminae*. If you want to be pretentious, write the *ae* as *æ*.

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** I'm incorporating what was discussed in the comments (thanks fdb).

A literal translation could be:

> **A viro ad mulierem**

Or the shorter:

> **Homo ad mulierem** (Man to woman)

- I prefer *[mulier](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dmulier)* over *[femina](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dfemina)*. Femina is, so to say, more biological, and also applies to female animals. Mulier, in turn, is more human-specific and arguably more fit for romanticism, since it's ambiguous and may also mean *wife* (if in context!... so don't worry).
- Ad + accusative (*ad feminam, ad mulierem*) is the standard way to tell to whom a letter or a poem is addressed to.
- [Ab](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dab) + dative (*ab homine*) is a way to tell who the *agent* is, but the nominative (homo) is also common (for example in letter openings).
- I can think of three ways to say *man*: *vir* (male correlative to *mulier*), *masculus* (male correlative to *femina*) and *homo*. The latter means man in the sense of human being, but has also the secondary meaning of man as opposed to woman (e.g. by Plautus in [Cist. 4.2](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0036%3Aact%3D4%3Ascene%3D2).57).

You could even make a more compact version, where a verb and an object are implied:

> **Vir mulieri** (a man [writes/reads this poem] to a woman)

Here, the dative (mulieri) makes the noun the indirect object (i.e. the recipient) of the (implied) action.

I like this one because of its compactness, ideal for a motto or for engraving. Its perfectly idiomatic in this context, although it could sound forced if spoken out of context.

Similar constructions using the same structure are:

> **Masculus feminae**, **homo mulieri**, etc.

A problem (or a potential advantageous fact) is that *feminae* means both *to [a|the] woman* and *[a|the] woman's*, hence *masculus feminae* can be read as both *man to woman* and *woman's man*. The precise word choice is up to you, depending on the nuances you want to give. You can even mix them (masculus mulieri/vir|homo feminae) but:

- Make sure to keep the right word endings (or the actual meaning can change)
- Keep also in mind that the mix could sound more or less as good or bad as these sound in English: male to woman, man to female.

Comment: That's great, n helps me a lot
Tho, I would not mind a biological context, so does homo feminam work? What's the dative for female in that context?

Comment: The opposite of mulier or femina is vir, not homo,

Comment: @KaushalSuvarna the two-word version would be _homo feminae_

Comment: @fdb I didn't feel the need to make the same contrast with the male words. It even seemed poetically appropriate to me as a way of praising her while belittling him (the speaker). Do you think the answer is better if it addresses homo vs vir too?

Comment: I should like to keep it biological, as long as we understand that we are talking about the biological aspects of men n women, love in a primal way

Comment: So if vir feminae is going to sound like a biology lecture, I'd prefer homo feminae to keep some poetry

Comment: Or how abt vir mulier as a kind of an appeal from a baser man to the femininity in woman?

Comment: @KaushalSuvarna the logical pairs are (as pointed by fdb): vir/mulier and masculus/feminae. In fact homo as specifically male is rare, but happens (e.g. in Plautus, who opposes it to mulier). Hence "man to woman" can be _masculus feminae_ ("biological" pair) or _vir mulieri_ (comprehensive pair). You can also mix the two, taking care not to change wired endings, or you can mix the whole meaning

Comment: @KaushalSuvana IMHO, _primal_ human love needs some kind of spiritual link, otherwise it would be indistinguishable from sexual attraction. But don't mind me: this consideration goes beyond the word choice. You can still mean what you want with the alternatives given. It's more of a matter of nuances at this point

Comment: I meant take care not to change WORD endings, sorry.

Comment: feminae can be dative or genitive ("a woman's man"). mulieri is unambiguous.

Comment: Rafael and fdb thanks a bunch for the help and explanations. Without going too much into the poem, it's an address from the base nature of man (and woman) to the discerning femininity in woman. So I think, tho it might break the logical pairing, "homo mulieri" makes most sense, esp now considering that homo is a neutral word.

Answer (score 0):

> *A viro mulieri (datus est).*

Would be a literal phrase, like what you would pot on a gift, but since this is more like a letter than anything, it would be more like:

> *Vir mulieri Sal.* or *Vir mulieri s.p.d.*